# Drawable tinting code works for Vectors but not PNGs

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable, tint, android-vectordrawable

So I am running into a weird issue... I have made some code to tint a Drawable, and it is working on all Android versions for Vector assets, but not for regular PNG assets. The code is below:

```
public class TintHelper {

    private Context mContext;

    public TintHelper(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public Drawable getTintedDrawableFromResource(int resourceID, ColorStateList colorStateList) {
        Drawable original = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(mContext, resourceID);
        return performTintOnDrawable(original, colorStateList);
    }

    private Drawable performTintOnDrawable(Drawable drawable, ColorStateList colorStateList) {
        Drawable tinted = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(tinted, colorStateList);
        return tinted;
    }
}
```

When I specify the resource ID of a vector asset, the code works perfectly and the image is tinted when pressed, but when I use a regular PNG, there is no tint applied when the icon is pressed. If anyone has any ideas of why this doesn't work, please post an alternative method that could potentially support both asset types.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of `appcompat-v7` / `support-v4`  are you using? the latest one? 24.2.0?

Comment: @pskink 24.2.1. See my answer below for the solution.

Comment: it just works with 24.2.0, i (double) checked that, no need for a custom view

Answer (score 0):

It is work for PNG in my environment.

set like this:

```
int resourceID = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
TintHelper tintHelper = new TintHelper(this);
Drawable drawable = tintHelper.getTintedDrawableFromResource(resourceID,
        ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.colors));

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

colors.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: thanks, but it still wasn't working for me. I outlined my fix in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Essentially, `DrawableCompat.setTintList()` is not working as expected on Android 21 and above. This is due to their implementation not calling `invalidate()` when there are state changes. More details can be read on this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172067).

To get this tinting code working for all platforms and all resource types, I needed to create a custom ImageView class as shown below:

```
public class StyleableImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public StyleableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public StyleableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public StyleableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    // This is the function to override...
    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();    // THE IMPORTANT LINE
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone that has had to deal with a similar situation.